# Unlinking Tree & DNA on Ancestry

Tags: autosomal-dna, ancestry.com

I have my Ancestry DNA results linked to my Tree. If I choose to unlink, link to a different person or different tree will I lose any of my notes, groups etc?

I assume not, but thought it best to check first.

Obviously Thrulines will be affected, presumably this will update within a day or so.

Answer (score -2):

I believe these will keep as long as you don't remove the tree or individuals itself. Your right, the Thrulines will be affected.

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format which is quite different from bulletin boards, discussion forums and other Q&A sites you may be used to.  Is there something in Ancestry's help to support your assertion?  Have you personally done this and observed the results?